# How does minification of css files using laravel mix work?

Tags: css, minify, laravel-mix

Why does minified file equal to a non-minified?

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.styles([
    'public/some.css',
    'public/thing.css',
], 'public/css/index.css');

mix.minify('public/css/index.css');
```

When running `npm run production`, sizes are 128kB (both compressed)

```
   Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
               mix.js  511 bytes       0  [emitted]  mix
       /css/index.css     128 kB          [emitted]
   /css/index.min.css     128 kB          [emitted]
```

When running `npm run dev`, both files are of the same size and it is `160 kB`, i.e. both are non-minified. How come a minified version is dependent not upon a `min` suffix, but on a dev\prod option?

Comment: Are you asking how compression works?

Comment: I'm trying to understand, why it works so strange)

Comment: I don't know why `dev` won't minify like `prod` but I think it's not useful to minify on `dev`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As from this [laravel-mix issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1295) Jeffrey points out that minification only happens in production mode. So to minify your css files, you can have:

`mix.styles([
    'public/some.css',
    'public/thing.css',
], 'public/css/index.css')`

Then running the following will concatenate and minify your files.

`$ npm run production`

Works for
`(laravel-mix@1.0)`